# Allow Remote Access to Sql Server Database in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, connection, connection-string

I have my `Database.mdf` that is located in `C:\Program Files\My Database`. 
When I'm accessing it at runtime (using my vb.net program) I have an error saying that

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

The thing that I am trying to do here is to allow other users to access the same database via LAN while using different computers.

Comment: What's your connection string looks like?

Comment: you don't access an sql database via file-access, not like microsoft access. You access the SQL server with a connection string.

Comment: Post the code that you're using "trying to access it during runtime". Without it, we'd just be guessing at what's wrong. You've provided no specific information here.

Comment: Post the connection string.   @JosephLee with Compact can actually connect with the file but doubt that is the case here.

Comment: Follow these instructions -  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: Here is my database's connection string:Data Source=ACE-DUO;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\My Database\db_CVSO.mdf;Integrated Security=True

I'm try to use it in a different computer but It needs the connection string to be changed inside the program for it to run

Comment: For starters, stop using `AttachDbFileName` - attach the database to a proper instance of SQL Server and then connect to that instance and reference the logical database name. The connection string shouldn't include a path to the physical file except for local development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed now to do what it is that I want. By enabling the **SQL Server Browser** and **TCP/IP** from *SQL Server Configuration Manager*, setting up the **TCP Port** from it's *Properties* to **1433**. Allowing an **Exception** for **Port 1433** in your **Firewall**, then using a Connection string that points into your Server's Sql Server. It will allow other users to access your SQL Database.

Like this:

```
dbConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=MYSERVER-NAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;User ID=sa;Password=pass")
```

In researching, this page helped a lot [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/)